# Eliminate irrelevant points based on time and distance

Tags: postgis, gps, tracking, movement-data

I'm collecting raw GPS points from android device for tracking, now when i'm creating a linestring based on the points i collected there are some points which makes no sense (due to GPS fluctuations). I have created a query to select only those coordinates which are satisfying a condition i.e (1.4 meter in 1 sec) which is average human walking distance. But still some points are zigzag. I'm not an expert in gis and also PostGIS

Here is the query i used

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM location_history a 
JOIN location_history b 
  ON (a.id+1 = b.id) 
where a.socket_client_id=187 and DATE(a.date_time)='2019-04-17' 
  and ST_DistanceSphere(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(a.lng, a.lat), 4326), 
                        ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(b.lng, b.lat), 4326))
      <= ((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (b.date_time - a.date_time)))*1.4) 
order by a.date_time;
```

Here are some points which are zigzag

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the resulting speeds of those instances of zigzag?

Comment: no but according to the theory those points satisfying the fact of 1.4 meter in 1 second.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: What does the output of the query look like? Your approach seems reasonable, but you dont say how it fails.

Comment: @JohnPowell my objective is to eliminate the point long in distance (due to gps fluctuations) i manage to eliminate some but the query eliminates a pair of coordinates which is also an issue.  my query failed as it detects points which can be reached at 1.4m/s but some points pass the condition which resulting some irrelevant linestring forming.

Comment: I understood the question, but not how it was failing -- if you could edit the question with that information, rather than put it in the comments, it would be helpful. The query looks reasonable, so, without some test data, it think it will be hard to track down.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/detecting-and-fixing-outliers-in-a-gps-trajectory/174098#174098