# Reconstruction of a geometric graph: link only vertices with no vertices in-between

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, graph, mathematics

I'm a mathematician who got lost here looking for the name of a graph construction.
Sorry if my question is silly/out-of-topic, but it seemed like a good place to ask.

I hope my notations are going to be intelligible, but I'm not very aware of the GIS conventions.

---

My initial problem is to construct a graph from a set of points *(s_i)_i=((x_i,y_i))_i* which are going to be my vertices. I can thus define the usual Euclidian distance *d(s,t)* between my vertices.

Now I want to add edges to my graph *G=(V,E)*,  so it looks like the road map (which I don't have and want to infer).

I could join each vertex *s_i* to its *k* nearest neighbours, but then I won't get the type of connection I want.

My idea is to connect two nodes *s,t* if there is no other vertex in the graph near the geodesic between *s* and *t*. The condition looks like

*(s,t)* is an edge  iff  there is no *u in V* (different from *s* or *t*} such that *d(s,u) + d(u,t) <= (1+r) d(s,t)*

(here *r* is some positive parameter controlling how close to the geodesic a node can be).

---

*example*

If the points are  *(0,0),(-2,0), (-1,0), (4,0), (0.01,0.5)* and *(0,1)* then

**if *r = 0***
the neighbours of *s=(0,0)$* will be *{(-1,0),(4,0), (0.01,0.5), (0,1) }$* (but not *t=(-2,0)* because for *u=(-1,0)* we have *d(s,u) + d(u,t) = (1+r) d(s,t)*

**if *r = 0.1***
the neighbours of *s=(0,0)* will be *{(-1,0),(4,0), (0.01,0.5)}* (but not *t=(0,1)* because for *u=(0.01,0.5)* we have *d(s,u) + d(u,t) < (1+r) d(s,t)*.

---

I would like to know if such a construction has a name, since I could not find one.

Comment: I'd think that [math.se] would be a better fit. There's certainly nothing GIS-centric about this Question.

Comment: I tried mathematics first, but its too geographic for there, hence I got no answer either. Sorry for the off-topic then

Comment: A diagram might help (we're mapping people), but naming such relationships isn't generally our thing.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/detecting-and-fixing-outliers-in-a-gps-trajectory#174133